# Do I have to use Getx Controller for all in my Flutter App?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

A developer friend of mine told that if I use getX, I have to use getx's on navigator. So you cannot use flutter's navigator. Same for Clipboard and MediaQuery.

Is it correct? I searched about this topic but did not find any proper answer.

I acutally learn what are the restrictions and the flutter's or custom packages that I cannot use if I use getx

Comment: Yes you can use GetX alongside with Flutter's navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use Flutter's navigation, clipboard, mediaQuery and everything else, and other custom libraries using GetX.
GetX is also a one of custom libraries so there's no any restriction.